# juddering on my steering wheel when braking…

Tags: brakes, nissan, x-trail

I have a 2018 xtrail… I had my brake pads changed recently, they had an issue recalibrating the brakes afterwards… it took ages! And since having this done I have had a judder on the steering wheel when braking and my brakes need to be pumped for the car to stop … ! Brakes seem spongy…
Can anyone please advise?
The garage seem to be fobbing me off and telling me it will settle in time…

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

Your garage is serving you a baloney sandwich.

Guess what? There is no "calibration" needed on Xtrail brakes. Your garage is lying to you because they are incompetent and they are hoping that, now that they have your money, you will just go away. And apparently they don't care if you live or die. Nice guys!

Before you drive this vehicle, you might want to call your insurance company and see if they will cover any damage, injury or death that results from your driving a vehicle ***that you know*** has spongy brakes and you have to pump the brakes repeatedly to stop. I'm not serious, but you do have a serious, dangerous situation here and some hard decisions to make. This car should not be driven on public roads. You could be criminally liable if you cause an accident knowing that you have bad brakes.

You need to find an honest, competent mechanic who can fix your car. Brakes are not hard. Check with friends, relatives, co-workers, neighbors. Find a mechanic that's recommended by someone you trust. Tell them what's wrong, ask them to send a tow truck and have the mechanic review the incompetent work that was done, write it up, and then let them fix your car.

If you are so disposed, then go back to the bozo mechanic, show them what it cost you to fix their shoddy work, and ask them to refund what you paid them. If they ask why you didn't give them a chance to fix the problem, remind them that they told you to keep driving and it would fix itself. (And you can throw in what your insurance company said about driving the car.)